# How to build a JS toggler that either opens or closes based on the click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/y2aFF/

This will open box1 or open box 2 if you click back and forth. What it doesn't do is if box 1 is open and you click box 1, I want it to close box 1. Same goes with box 2. Any elegant way to do this with js/jQuery?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your example doesn't actually work because it has errors and is set to use Mootools not jQuery.

Try this example to see how you could do it: http://jsfiddle.net/zs7xF/1/

Comment: Forked so it closes box on 2nd click as requested: http://jsfiddle.net/xG3TR/

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've clarified your question, you can use this jQuery to just have each button toggle it's own box:

```
$(".buttons").click(function() {
    $("#" + $(this).val()).toggle();
});
```

And, a working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/WTCgP/

---

Previous suggestions:

I'd suggest more jQuery-like code like this:

HTML:

```
<input class="buttons" type="button" value="box1">
<input class="buttons" type="button" value="box2">

<div id="box1" style="display:none;">box 1</div>
<div id="box2" style="display:none;">box 2</div
```

Code (runs after page load):

```
$(".buttons").click(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'box1') {
        $('#box1').show();
        $('#box2').hide();
    } else {
        $('#box2').show();
        $('#box1').hide();
    }
});
```

And, a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/rKn3j/.

Notice I've separated all code from the markup by attaching event handlers instead of putting code in the markup.

If you really want a toggle function, you may want to look at the jQuery toggle function which can toggle the display of an object with a single function call.

Comment: Thanks but that misses the question. If box1 is open and you click box1 I want box1 to close and box 2 to stay closed

Comment: OK, I added a new approach at the start of my answer where each button just toggle's it's own box.